# Title in matlab graph subplot

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, subplot

I've created a matlab graph in my Tkinter GUI. Which is part of a bigger GUI class. I'm having issues with adding a title.

Question: Does anyone know how I give my subplots a title ?

```
self.f = plt.Figure(figsize=(4,5), dpi=90)

    self.a = self.f.add_subplot(211)
    self.a.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [5, 6, 1, 7, 4, 2, 5, 0])
    self.a.plt.ylabel('some numbers')

    self.b = self.f.add_subplot(212)
    self.b.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 3, 6, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0])

    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, master=self.frame1)
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

Simply adding the following code doesn't work.

```
self.a.plt.title('some numbers')
```

Comment: try self.a.set_title('the title you want')

Comment: You're amazing! It works, I was so close yet so far away haha. Thx alot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is an example from matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html)

Matplotlib has standards I haven't quite fully comprehended yet, but it seems that which method you use to do something like set a title depends on if you're using a fig, plot, or axis...in this case, the answer is:

```
self.a.set_title('title goes here for your subplot')
```